# C++ cast notation of explicit type conversion (C-style cast) and multiple interpretations of static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

[Paragraph 4 of [expr.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4) (in the latest draft of the C++ standard available at the time of writing) which describes the behaviour of a C-style cast says the following:

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_­cast`, or
> - a `reinterpret_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, with the exception that in performing a `static_­cast` in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible:
>
> - a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue or rvalue of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;
> - a pointer to member of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer to member of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type;
> - a pointer to an object of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type, a glvalue of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type, or a pointer to member of an unambiguous non-virtual base class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer, a reference, or a pointer to member of a derived class type, respectively.
>
> If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed. **If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one way as a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`, the conversion is ill-formed**. [...]

My question is how can "*a conversion be interpreted in more than one way as a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`*"?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but the first sentence says: "[...] the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed". Using static_cast to cast to an ambiguous base class is ill-formed, so the highlighted sentence is not necessary anymore. Also, the highlighted sentence singles out a more specific case: "a static_­cast followed by a const_­cast".

Comment: Something like this: a class with two user-defined conversion operators, one to `int const **` and another to `int* const *`. The C-style cast is to `int**` [Demo](http://rextester.com/RAGJ13771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
struct S {
    operator int const**() { return nullptr; }
    operator int *const*() { return nullptr; }
};

S s;
(int**)s;  // error: cannot cast from type 'S' to pointer type 'int **'
```

Similar casts to `int const**` and `int *const*` succeed. [Demo](http://rextester.com/RAGJ13771)

Comment: Thank you! And this is not a problem for `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast` because `reinterpret_cast` is free to cast directly to a type similar (or identical) to the destination type, but at least as cv-qualified as the source type, and then let the `const_cast` cast away the constness, correct? Therefore there cannot be multiple options for the "intermediary" type.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` doesn't use conversion operators. It can't cast from non-pointer to pointer in the first place.

Comment: I had in mind a different example (https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-head/permlink/pJMBr70taUyQnIiN). When a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast` is necessary, it is because the destination type is "less cv-qualified" than the source type (because otherwise `reinterpret_cast` would have been chosen, as it is higher on the list). Therefore `reinterpret_cast` is used to convert to a type similar to the destination type, but at least "as cv-qualified" as the source type.

Comment: That is because, as you said, reinterpret_cast is not concerned by whether the source type is implicitly or explicitly convertible to the destination type. Then the const_cast is used to cast away the constness. However, if we had something like (int **) v, where v's type is, for example, (const X **), that C-style cast could be interpreted as const_cast<int **>(reinterpret_cast<const int * const *>(v)) (that is, reinterpret_cast could add some more constness). But this choice has no observable side-effects, unlike choosing between two conversion operators, as in your example.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "_It can't cast from non-pointer to pointer in the first place_" You certainly meant from class object to pointer.